# CONSTRAINT CHECK in Oracle SQL (white case)

Tags: oracle, constraints

i have table of cars and i need to put constraint,

**if car.speed<1200 then price<=90000**

I try this:

```
ALTER TABLE CARS ADD CONSTRAINT price_speed_chk CHECK(
CASE WHEN speed <1200  THEN price<=90000 );
```

it's doesn't work.

who can help ? 
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/CASE-statement.htm#LNPLS01304) completely a wrong way.
If you need a check with that logic, you can simply use some boolean operators:

```
ALTER TABLE CARS ADD CONSTRAINT price_speed_chk CHECK(speed >= 1200  OR price<=90000 );
```